# XGBoost: fit() got an unexpected keyword argument 'xgb_model'

Tags: python, xgboost

According to the documentation, it should be possible to write the code like this:

```
# Instantiate the model
model = XGBClassifier() 
model.fit(x, y, xgb_model='model.xgb')
```

But it fails with :

> TypeError: fit() got an unexpected keyword argument 'xgb_model'

The reference:
http://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/python/python_api.html

> xgb_model (str) – file name of stored xgb model or ‘Booster’ instance Xgb model to be loaded before training (allows training continuation).

Am I missing anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`xgb_model` argument [was added to the `fit()` method quite recently](https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost/commit/9a81c74a7bd8db06c2f2ccb28b88ffeecf4c0309) (Oct 1). Make sure you have the latest `xgboost` version installed.